# Python unable to decode byte string

Tags: python, encoding, decode

I am having problem with decoding byte string that I have to send from one computer to another. File is format PDF. I get error that goes:

```
fileStrings[i] = fileStrings[i].decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 648: invalid continuation byte
```

Any ideas of how to remove b' ' marking? I need to compile file back up, but i also need to know its size in bytes before sending it and I figured I will know it by decoding each byte string (Works for txt files but not for pdf ones..)

Code is:

```
    with open(inputne, "rb") as file:
        while 1:
            readBytes= file.read(dataMaxSize)
            fileStrings.append(readBytes)
            if not readBytes:
                break
            readBytes= ''
    
    filesize=0
    for i in range(0, len(fileStrings)):
        fileStrings[i] = fileStrings[i].decode()
        filesize += len(fileStrings[i])
```

Edit: For anyone having same issue, parameter len() will give you size without b''.

Comment: "size in bytes" - decoding would translate bytes to characters, and the number of characters is not the same as the number of bytes. `∞` is one symbol but 3 bytes: `b'\xe2\x88\x9e'`, or 8 bytes in UTF32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, bytestrings are for raw binary data, and strings are for textual data. `decode` tries to decode it as utf-8, which is valid for txt files, but not for pdf files, since they can contain random bytes. You **should not** try to get a string, since bytestrings are **designed** for this purpose. You can get the length of bytestrings like normal, with `len(data)`. Many of the string operations also apply to bytestrings, such as concatenation and slicing (`data1 + data2` and `data[1:3]`).

As a side note, the `b''` when you print it is just because the `__str__` method for bytestrings is equivalent to `repr`. It's not in the data itself.

Comment: Doesn't it count b' ' into size when I use len()? EDIT: No it doesn't count b' ' into len, as side note for someone having same issue as me. Thanks for your answer @Aplet123 , it helped.